# Cisco Nexus syslog messages format?

Tags: cisco, syslog, windows-event-log, cisco-nexus

I'm trying to normalize Syslog messages generated by a Cisco Nexus box.
Problem: Messages have the following format:

<189>: yyyy mm dd hh:mm:ss UTC: text

This is not a standard Syslog message, no hostname/IP address is displayed. Someone knows how those messages are generated? Can I adapt the format on the Nexus itself?

/x

Comment: What kinda Nexus is it? 5000 or 7000? Is this the syslog message on the device, or do you send it to a logserver?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
logging server X.X.X.X 7 use-vrf default
logging monitor 7
logging level local0 7
logging level local1 7
logging level local2 7
logging level local3 7
logging level local4 7
logging level local5 7
logging level local6 7
logging level local7 7
logging logfile messages 6
```

Which gives:

```
2012 Nov  8 19:05:48 NEXUS01 %AUTHPRIV-5-SYSTEM_MSG:
```